# Where to find logarithmic graph of Bitcoin over time?

Tags: value, charts

I'd like to find a logarithmic graph of the value of BTC vs the simple USD/time graph. Any suggestions of where to find that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure what you mean by logarithmic graph. The time in a logarithmic scale, or the value? On both, there is a "log" button below the graph. And you can export as CSV or JSON:

https://blockchain.info/de/charts/market-price?timespan=all

or alternativly:

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/

Comment: @Hollossy For what it's worth, I found another at: https://charts.bitcoin.com/chart/price#lc

Answer (score 0):

http://bitcoin.zorinaq.com/price/ goes back to 2010-04-25, which is the furthest I've seen.